# Install elpy on emacs

Tags: python, config, ide

I checked  [the elpy site](https://elpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html) but came across an error where the package cannot be found? I am new to emacs and need a little help reading the error message.

The specific code in the init file I tried to verify using the C-x C-e command is
`(use-package elpy :ensure t :init (elpy-enable))`
which is what the documentation recommends.

Computer set up-
Arch Linux /
GNU Emacs 29.2 /
Linux LTS kernel

[image]

**UPDATE** I checked the elpy config and got this result [image]

Apparently ELPY is out of date or very old? If anyone has any other alternatives I would love to try them out.
The main goal is to just get IDE functionality (syntax highlighting, auto complete, debugger ect...) that not only include Python but maybe other languages if possible?
Any help would be awesome

Comment: Not sure what exactly causes this message, but maybe you can try installing `elpy` via `M-x package-list-packages`, while making sure that you install from the 'melpa-stable' archive.

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment, I installed elpy through that command and used the M-x command to run "elpy-enable" but when I then open up a python file I do not get any of the features still.

Comment: If you'd like to use a debugger, then probably LSP-mode will be easiest to use. Otherwise, indeed, as mentioned by @Ian, go with eglot. Personally, I think the best option for a starter is to use a starter kit like Spacemacs or Doom Emacs, they are great (and can be used with Emacs keybindings, although the experience is better when using vim/evil keybindings).

Answer (score 0):

At this stage of your installation (according to your comment), all you need to do further is the command `M-x elpy-config` which will check your installation and will show you need to have some mandatory python packages  to be installed.

However, since you already have Emacs 29.2, you can use the built-in package [eglot](https://github.com/joaotavora/eglot), which is better and up to date (note elpy is already ten years old and unmaintained). On the provided link you will find out a link to eglot manual.

Comment: Right ok, I will give that a go. I thought elpy was the main option but I will check out other packages that provide Python IDE functionality.